# Renting Bandwith Overhead

Tags: web-server, hosting, cloud

***Preface***

I have my own servers that have been given to me by a company I used to work for. I want to use these servers for some sites I've developed. I'm expecting a good amount of traffic and don't want to be limited by my ISP.

***Question***

Are there any service providers that'll allow me to "park" my servers on their premises to take advantage of their networking infrastructure? If so, what are these types of service providers called?

*Feel free to expound upon this topic, the more information I can garner the better my decision will be.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're generally called colocation datacenters, and you can expect to pay dearly for space there. :)

Comment: ah ok, yes. colocation does ring a bell now that you say it, heard that used before. :) are there any "entry level" colocation providers out there that you know of? i don't much in the way of "dispensible income" as my day job can't pay the bill for costly hosting...

Comment: @Curiosity - sorry, service and product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: bah. you're right. :/